# save table row contains table data and text fields, in row wise

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel-5.3

Please can anyone suggest me what would be the good approach to save all the fields data. for reference I am attaching my requirement image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/babsz.png)

Comment: can you please add more details here. a fiddle example or anything as such help us to help you out

Comment: thanks for your reply ankit, I have added image over there that is a webpage, they are having different different formulas  for calculating some fields with onchange event. I have done the client side formula calculations. now I have to save the whole data nearly 90 fileds. In a table 90 columns if i create it is not efficient way, so I want to insert row wise. each TR as a row and TR will contain text fields.

Comment: Hey can you add the html and the Js function over here so can have we can have a clear picture